# wcf issues on IIS

Tags: wcf, iis

After deploying WCF server (svc) on my Server, I have got this message when accessing on: https://test.com/myService.svc

> 404 - File or directory not found.

Following this post: http://geekswithblogs.net/amaniar/archive/2010/08/31/wcf--iis7-404-file-or-directory-not-found.aspx

I activated the WCF server.

Then, I run: https://test.com/myService.svc and it works only the first time. after that, I can not access IIS any more: Internal Error

This is my binding and service:

```
 <binding name="BindTest">
      <binaryMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="16" maxSessionSize="2048">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="10242880" maxArrayLength="10242880" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      </binaryMessageEncoding>
      <httpsTransport />
    </binding> 

<service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior123" name="xyz">
        <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="BindTest" name="ServiceEndpoint" contract="ISerice" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="ServiceMexEndpoint" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
```

I can not access on my IIS anymore. If I remove WCF activation, my web works again but the service wcf svc is not found.

Comment: Are you using a custom `Factory` in your `ServiceHost` directive in your `.svc` file?

Comment: I am not familiar with this as I am new with WCF.

Comment: You're probably not then ... :) but for future reference - [@ServiceHost Directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa967286.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible your service is crashing repeatedly, which causes IIS to shut the app pool down.

if you stop and restart IIS, you will be able to run it again.

The solution though, is to correct your implementation - your code - to prevent the crash.

The crash can be due to an invalid cast, a null pointer exception, and so on.  Use try...catch to prevent and diagnose such crashes.

Comment: try catch works. but then why it is working normally without http? thanks in advance.